# How to multiple push to nested array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5bd"),
    "companyBases" : [
        {
            "vehicles" : [],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5b0"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 3",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.01744,
                "lat" : 20.033522
            },
            "country" : ObjectId("5d7052a2807ab14e286ba578"),
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "vehicles" : [],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5af"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 2",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.036017,
                "lat" : 20.086752
            },
            "country" : ObjectId("5d7052a2807ab14e286ba578"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "nameOfCompany" : "Transport Tech Service 2 ",
    "plan" : {
        "name" : "Enterprise",
        "vehicles" : 56,
        "companyBases" : 10,
        "users" : 10,
        "price" : 1200
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
 db.companies.update(
        {
          _id: ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5bd")
        },
        {
          $push: {
            "companyBases.$[filter1].vehicles": {
                "name": "Truck 1",
                "combustion": 28
            },
            "companyBases.$[filter2].vehicles": {
                "name": "Truck 2",
                "combustion": 28
            }
          }
        },
        {
            "arrayFilters": [
                {
                    "filter1._id": "5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5b0"
                },
                {
                    "filter2._id": "5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5af"
                }
            ]
        }
      )
```

But, it doesn't update my nested arrays "vehicles"

It returns me:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

I checked IDs and it's ok. I've created similar question a few days ago but with $set pipeline not $push - [How to update in one query, multiple times without sharing to simple queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699721/how-to-update-in-one-query-multiple-times-without-sharing-to-simple-queries) , but i was thinking it's possible to rewrite that example to $push.

Comment: Your query seems to be perfect. Can you please share the document with object id ```ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5bd")```

Comment: I updated with real object store in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue: In array filters, the _id is matched with string instead of ObjectId**

The following query would precisely update the collection:

```
db.companies.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5bd")
    }, 
    {
        $push: {
            "companyBases.$[filter1].vehicles": {
                "name": "Truck 1",
                "combustion": 28
            },
            "companyBases.$[filter2].vehicles": {
                "name": "Truck 2",
                "combustion": 28
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "arrayFilters": [{
                "filter1._id": ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5b0")
            },
            {
                "filter2._id": ObjectId("5d7052a3807ab14e286ba5af")
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Yeah, now it's working, i forgot to wrap in ObjectId.

Comment: @Himanshu, you saved my day. Solved this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915760/upsert-in-nested-array-doesnt-create-parent-document/68916266?noredirect=1#comment121808804_68916266