# Upsert in nested array doesn't create parent document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Schema

```
{
    chapter: {
        required: true,
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Chapter",
    },
    questions: {
        type: [Number]
    },
};
```

Here is an example document

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5ff4b728b6af610f0851d2a6"
   },
   "chapters":[
      {
         "chapter":{
            "$oid":"611478ab34dde61f28dbe4d3"
         },
         "questions":[
            35,
            29,
            167,
            180,
            101,
            16,
            71,
            23
         ]
      },
      {
         "chapter":{
            "$oid":"611478ac34dde61f28dbe4d8"
         },
         "questions":[
            162
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to "$addToSet" on "questions", such as

```
const someId = SOME_ID;
const chapterId = "611478ac34dde61f28dbe4d8";
const update = {
    $addToSet: {
        "chapters.$.questions": {
            $each: [5, 10, 32, 6],
        },
    },
};
await model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: someId,
        "chapters.chapter": chapterId,
    },
    update,
    { upsert: true }
)
    .lean()
    .exec();
```

This works. However, if there is no document, the "upsert" doesn't create the document.
How can I rewrite the operation so that it can update (addToSet) as well as ensure the document is created if it didn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, for some reason, I can't $addToSet if the parent object is not present. So I had to make one more operation.

Inspired from [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808414/1914985).

1. I fetch the "chapters" which I need to add.
2. From this list of fetched chapters, I check which ones exist and which ones don't.
3. Using the knowledge from point 2, I am using $push to add the chapters which didn't exist entirely, and "adding to set ($addToSet)" questions on the chapters which do exist.

I am posting the code which works for me.

```
//Data to add (which chapter?: questionNumber[])
const docId = "SOMEID";
const questionsToAdd = {
    "611478ab34dde61f28dbe4d3": [1,5,6,10],
    "611478ab34dde61f28dbe4d8": [5,8,20,30],
};

//Find the chapters from questionsToAdd which exist
const existingDoc = await model.findOne({
    _id: docId,
    chapters: { $elemMatch: { chapter: { $in: Object.keys(questionsToAdd) } } },
})
    .select(["chapters.chapter"])
    .lean()
    .exec();

// Objectify the array of chapters
const existingChapters = (existingDoc?.chapters ?? []).map((x) => "" + x.chapter);

// Prepare what to insert, what to update
const updateObject = {
    $addToSet: {},
    arrayFilters: [],
    $push: [],
};
for (const [index, [chapterId, questionIndices]] of Object.entries(questionsToAdd).entries()) {
    if (existingChapters.includes(chapterId)) {
        updateObject.$addToSet["chapters.$[filter" + index + "].questions"] = { $each: questionIndices };
        updateObject.arrayFilters.push({
            ["filter" + index + ".chapter"]: Types.ObjectId(chapterId),
        });
    } else {
        updateObject.$push.push({
            chapter: chapterId,
            questions: questionIndices,
        });
    }
}

if (updateObject.arrayFilters.length) {
    // *Add to set the chapters which exist
    await model.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        {
            $addToSet: updateObject.$addToSet,
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: updateObject.arrayFilters,
            upsert: true,
        }
    )
        .lean()
        .exec();
}

if (updateObject.$push.length) {
    // *Push the ones that does not exist
    await model.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        {
            $push: { chapters: updateObject.$push },
        },
        {
            upsert: true,
        }
    )
        .lean()
        .exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked MongoDB native query use these

```
db.con.collection('example').updateOne(
    {"chapters": {$elemMatch:{"chapter.id":ObjectId("611478ac34dde61f28dbe4d8")}}},
    {$addToSet: {
        "chapters.$.questions": {
            $each: [5, 10, 32, 6],
        },
    }},
    {upsert: true})
```

you should find the element of array using elemMatch

```
{"chapters": {$elemMatch:{"chapter.id":"611478ac34dde61f28dbe4d8"}}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when there is no document. It returns "BadValue" error.

Comment: is chapter object in chapters array , or chapters array is your collection ?

Comment: You can see the example document structure I have in the question. Chapter object is in chapters array.

Comment: ok my query is mongo query not mongoose did you translate my query to mongoose?

Comment: Yes I did, but it turns out the $addToSet only works if the parent object is present. I instead replaced it with a combination of ArrayFilters and $push, inspired from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57808414/1914985

Comment: did you use {$elemMatch:{"chapter.id":ObjectId("611478ac34dde61f28dbe4d8")}} ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, if the entire document is not there, then this upsert isn't creating the document. This only works if the document exist. By document, I mean the document which contains "chapter" object inside that I am trying to update. If the document exist (which I mentioned in my quesiton as "SOME_ID") then this works.

But many thanks for your help. I figured out a way to do this, as I mentioned in my answer here. I up-voted your approach though, you helped me go towards the right direction. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you , could you change the chapter.id in element match to some id didnt exit , to check how upsert works?